# The Raspberry pi 3 B v1.2 нет красного индикатора, она сильно нагревается, но продолжает работать

Tags: raspberry-pi

Раньше такого не случалось, но сегодня я заметил, что на raspberry не загорается красный индикатор. В то же время зеленый продолжает работать. Плата тоже работает исправно, подключается к Wi-Fi и ssh работает. Но микросхема очень горячая, показывает 90°C (я побоялся заходить дальше).
Почему мог перестать работать красный индикатор и появится сильный нагрев при простоях?

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! переведите, пожалуйста, текст вопроса (нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса) на русский язык